# Colour area above y-lim in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

How can I colour the area between y=0 and the datapoints in green? At the moment it is colouring the whole y [0:1]

```
Variable <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    value <- c(-0.26, -0.10,0.98,0.52, 0.31, -0.63, -0.70)
    df <- data.frame(Variable, value)
    
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(value,1), ymax=0), fill="red", col="red", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=pmax(df$value,1)), fill="green", col="green", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), color="black") + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really not a direct way to do this in ggplot2 as far as I know. If you didn't want the transparency, then it would be pretty easy just to draw a rectangle in the background and then draw the ribbon on top.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=min(Variable), xmax=max(Variable), ymin=0, ymax=1), fill="green") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(value,1), ymax=0), fill="red", col="red") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), color="black") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

But if you need the transparency, you're going to need to calculate the bounds of that region which is messy because the points where the line crosses the axis are not in your data, you would need to calculate those. Here's a function that finds the places where the region crosses the axis and keeps track of the top points

```
crosses <- function(x, y) {
  outx <- x[1]
  outy <- max(y[1],0)
  for(i in 2:length(x)) {
    if (sign(y[i-1]) != sign(y[i])) {
      outx <- c(outx, -y[i-1]*(x[i]-x[i-1])/(y[i]-y[i-1])+x[i-1])
      outy <- c(outy, 0)
    }
    if (y[i]>0) {
      outx <- c(outx, x[i])
      outy <- c(outy, y[i])
    } 
  }
  if (y[length(y)]<0) {
    outx <- c(outx, x[length(x)])
    outy <- c(outy, 0)
  }
  data.frame(x=outx, y=outy)
}
```

Basically it's just doing some [two-point line formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Two-PointForm.html) stuff to calculate the intersection.

Then use this to create a new data frame of points for the top ribbon

```
top_ribbon <- with(df, crosses(Variable, value))
```

And plot it

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(value,1), ymax=0), fill="red", col="red", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y, ymax=1, x=x), fill="green", col="green", alpha=0.5, data=top_ribbon) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), color="black") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the image from the question in case I wasn't very specific. I thought with the two lines of geom_ribbon you could tell the plot to fill the area above or below your datapoints til y=0? I am not that worried about transparency but more about the colouring above and below. I can check for a similar post I saw a while back and paste the link!

Comment: Actually I found this, and worked! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947806/how-can-i-fill-the-space-between-valuesgeom-line-and-an-intercept-with-ggplot2

Comment: Well, using that answer you would have done `ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(value,0), ymax=0), fill="red", col="red", alpha=0.5) +geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=pmax(value,0)), fill="green", col="green", alpha=0.5)` but the problem is again, you don't have points where it actually crosses the axis so the ribbons don't look right. You're still going to have to calculate those values to add them in.

Comment: Maybe see also this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135962/how-to-fill-geom-polygon-with-different-colors-above-and-below-y-0

Comment: Thanks, as it seems odd with datapoints, it might be best to show geom_bar instead, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a related-post from 3 years ago [How can I fill the space between values(geom_line) and an intercept with ggplot2? Different Colors for values over and under intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947806/how-can-i-fill-the-space-between-valuesgeom-line-and-an-intercept-with-ggplot2)

For which I ran the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable,y=value)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(df$value,0), ymax=0), fill="blue", col="blue", alpha=0.5) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=pmax(df$value,0)), fill="green", col="green", alpha=0.5) +
geom_line(aes(y=0))
```

And worked like this: Although note the areas are a bit odd at the intersect!
[image]

Comment: Well, it made a plot two two different color. But notice how there's not a continuous line anymore. The areas overlap which isn't desired as far as I can tell from the OP.

Comment: Yes, it looks odd, like you said, the points dont't exactly coincide with y=0 ...