# R - Coloring the area under/above a line in different colours using geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, aesthetics, geom-ribbon

I have a simple line graph which fluctuates around zero.
Using geom_ribbon, I would like to color the area between the line and zero in two different colors, depending on whether the line is above or under zero.
Using a single color to fill the area works:

[image: geom_ribbon, single color]

However, my attempt to fill the area in different colours ([following this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277729))
fails as two seperate ribbons are created that either connect the points below or above zero.

```
df%>%
ggplot(aes(x=month, dif))+
geom_line()+
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", guide = guide_axis(angle = 90))+
geom_ribbon(aes(x=month, ymin=0, ymax=dif,  fill= dif>0), alpha=.5)+
scale_fill_manual(values=df$filler, name="fill")
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how this could be fixed?

Reproducible sample:

```
df<-structure(list(month = structure(c(17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866), class = "Date"), 
high = c(2618.74, 2453.39, 2075.89, 2535.89, 3331.15, 2238.85, 
3013.85, 3073.36, 2348.01, 3410.8, 653.56, 2840.22), low = c(3445.45, 
1352.91, 1594.51, 1344.27, 1676.73, 2410.76, 1289.4, 1330.72, 
1824.69, 1843.76, 1500.12, 3252.97), filler = c("red", "lightblue", 
"lightblue", "lightblue", "lightblue", "red", "lightblue", 
"lightblue", "lightblue", "lightblue", "red", "red"), dif = c(-826.71, 
1100.48, 481.38, 1191.62, 1654.42, -171.91, 1724.45, 1742.64, 
523.32, 1567.04, -846.56, -412.75)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Here's a recent blog post with a helper function for this situation: https://www.nsgrantham.com/fill-between-two-lines-ggplot2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill the space between values(geom\_line) and an intercept with ggplot2? Different Colors for values over and under intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947806/how-can-i-fill-the-space-between-valuesgeom-line-and-an-intercept-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

I found a very clean solution using `ggh4x` package. Here it is

```
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y = dif)) +
  ggh4x::stat_difference(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = dif)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = dif)) +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image]