# R - ggplot2: Fill only the area between a line and a reference value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot2 to produce a graph like the one below, where the area between the line and a reference value is shaded, and the color of the shading depends on whether y is greater or less than the reference value.

[image: CDC graph of 2020 primary and secondary syphilis cases relative to 2019 cases by reporting week]

Here's a reprex using the LakeHuron dataset, setting 579 as the reference value, and using `geom_ribbon()` to do the shading. This gets close, but I *only* want to fill the area between the line and the reference line.

```
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

ggplot(data = huron, aes(x = year)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 579, ymax = level, fill = level > 579)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 579)
```

[image: huron example]

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two ribbons if you want two different fills:

```r
ggplot(data = huron, aes(x = year)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 579, ymax = ifelse(level > 579, level, 579),
                  fill = "Above average")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = 579, ymin = ifelse(level > 579, 579, level),
                  fill = "Below average")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 579) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#86b2d8", "#bf311a"), name = NULL) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! While this definitely does what I was looking for, the ribbons still end up outside the line in places where it crosses the reference line. Any thoughts on how to clean up that overlap?

Answer (score 3):

A second option would be to use `ggh4x::stat_difference` which IMHO is one of the hidden gems of the `ggh4x` package:

```r
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(huron, aes(x = year)) +
  ggh4x::stat_difference(aes(ymin = 579, ymax = level), levels = c("Above average", "Below Average")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 579) +
  scale_fill_manual(limits = c("Above average", "Below Average"), values = rev(scales::hue_pal()(2))) +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image]