# I can't add more space between the y values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Now I'm working with this database:

```
structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
), saldo = c(8275867, 3702514, -2636805, -3665755, -5751042, 
841426, 48908, -4019329, -4943662, -2199522, 1060542, 6223146, 
16661053, 16087980, 12130455, 11699873, 12392519, 11272844, 12556386, 
16885829, 11381863, 9020415, 12008167, 1521176, 2668277.78157, 
-3419083.03045001, 2057032, -8308931, -3881619)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So this is my code to plot the trade balance time series of Argentina:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)    

    rx <- do.call("rbind",
              sapply(1:(nrow(TB_since_1990)-1), function(i){
                f <- lm(year~saldo, TB_since_1990[i:(i+1),])
                if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(saldo=0))
                if(TB_since_1990[i,]$year < r & r < TB_since_1990[i+1,]$year)
                  return(data.frame(year=r,saldo=0))
                else return(NULL)
              }))
newdata.df <- rbind(TB_since_1990, rx)
newdata.df <- newdata.df[order(newdata.df$saldo),]


color.plot <- "darkorchid4"
size.line <- 1.5

ggplot(newdata.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo, fill = "Trade balance")) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6) + 
  geom_line(color= color.plot, size = size.line) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  labs(fill= "", title="Argentina Trade Balance",x="",y="Saldo") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -10e6, to = 20e6, by = 2.5e6), 
                     limits = c(-10e6, 20e6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1990, to = 2018, by = 1), 
                     limits = c(1990, 2018)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Trade balance" = color.plot)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

This is my current plot:

[image]

I want this graph:

[image: I want this graph]

I don't know how to point out the negative values ​​of the y-axis in the plot. Also, I want to add more space between each value of the y-axis.

Comment: Why are you setting the axis breaks as the exact values in your data, instead of evenly spaced sequences?

Comment: @camille  My mistake, What should I do so that it is distributed in evenly spaced sequences?

Comment: I edited my answer with a "final" version of the plot. Please let me know if this works for you and up-vote and/or accept the answer if it solved your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @yarnabrina that `geom_area` is the option you need. However, `ggplot` needs some help to make exactly what you ask for, see below.

```
data.df <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
                               1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
                               2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
), saldo = c(8275867, 3702514, -2636805, -3665755, -5751042, 
             841426, 48908, -4019329, -4943662, -2199522, 1060542, 6223146, 
             16661053, 16087980, 12130455, 11699873, 12392519, 11272844, 12556386, 
             16885829, 11381863, 9020415, 12008167, 1521176, 2668277.78157, 
             -3419083.03045001, 2057032, -8308931, -3881619)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The graph using just `geom_area`

```
ggplot(data.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo)) + 
       geom_area() + 
       geom_line(color= "red") + 
       geom_point(color= "red")
```

[image]

I added a line and points to show your data. Now it is clear that `geom_area` does not work as you want when crossing the x-axis.

To fix this we need to add the y-axis crossing points to the data set. This can be done with a combination of `lm` and `predict` functions of R base.

See below the code to calculate the new points (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137211))

```
rx <- do.call("rbind",
              sapply(1:(nrow(data.df)-1), function(i){
                f <- lm(year~saldo, data.df[i:(i+1),])
                if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(saldo=0))
                if(data.df[i,]$year < r & r < data.df[i+1,]$year)
                  return(data.frame(year=r,saldo=0))
                else return(NULL)
              }))
newdata.df <- rbind(data.df, rx)
newdata.df <- newdata.df[order(newdata.df$saldo),]
```

and to plot the graph.

```
ggplot(newdata.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo)) + 
       geom_area() + 
       geom_line(color= "red") + 
       geom_point(color= "red")
```

[image]

Now it looks more like what you were looking for. The last thing would be to modify the code to make it nicer.

## Final plot

Set some values for easy configuration (you can find more color options [here](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) or using google ^_^)

```
color.plot <- "darkorchid4"
size.line <- 1.5
```

**option 1**

```
ggplot(newdata.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo, color = "Trade balance")) + 
  geom_area(fill = color.plot, alpha = 0.6, size = size.line) + 
  # geom_line(color= color.plot, size = size.line) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = size.line) +
  labs(color= "", title="Argentina Trade Balance",x="",y="Saldo") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -10e6, to = 20e6, by = 2.5e6), 
                     limits = c(-10e6, 20e6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1990, to = 2018, by = 1), 
                     limits = c(1990, 2018)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Trade balance" = color.plot)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**option 2**

```
ggplot(newdata.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo, fill = "Trade balance")) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6) + 
  geom_line(color= color.plot, size = size.line) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  labs(fill= "", title="Argentina Trade Balance",x="",y="Saldo") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -10e6, to = 20e6, by = 2.5e6), 
                     limits = c(-10e6, 20e6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1990, to = 2018, by = 1), 
                     limits = c(1990, 2018)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Trade balance" = color.plot)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**Answer to question edit**

I am not sure where your problem is. In my computer it works perfectly, and produces a plot like the last one in my post.

I added here the full code to produce the plot just in case it may be useful, in fact everything but creating the initial data frame is a direct copy/paste of the code in your question.

```
TB_since_1990 <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
                        1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
                        2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
), saldo = c(8275867, 3702514, -2636805, -3665755, -5751042, 
             841426, 48908, -4019329, -4943662, -2199522, 1060542, 6223146, 
             16661053, 16087980, 12130455, 11699873, 12392519, 11272844, 12556386, 
             16885829, 11381863, 9020415, 12008167, 1521176, 2668277.78157, 
             -3419083.03045001, 2057032, -8308931, -3881619)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

rx <- do.call("rbind",
              sapply(1:(nrow(TB_since_1990)-1), function(i){
                f <- lm(year~saldo, TB_since_1990[i:(i+1),])
                if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(saldo=0))
                if(TB_since_1990[i,]$year < r & r < TB_since_1990[i+1,]$year)
                  return(data.frame(year=r,saldo=0))
                else return(NULL)
              }))
newdata.df <- rbind(TB_since_1990, rx)
newdata.df <- newdata.df[order(newdata.df$saldo),]


color.plot <- "darkorchid4"
size.line <- 1.5

ggplot(newdata.df, aes(x=year, y=saldo, fill = "Trade balance")) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6) + 
  geom_line(color= color.plot, size = size.line) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  labs(fill= "", title="Argentina Trade Balance",x="",y="Saldo") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -10e6, to = 20e6, by = 2.5e6), 
                     limits = c(-10e6, 20e6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1990, to = 2018, by = 1), 
                     limits = c(1990, 2018)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Trade balance" = color.plot)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Based on your image looks like ggplot is not interpreting the color properly and, more important, geom_area is not working as expected. You may want to install ggplot again or try the code in a different computer. Good luck!

Comment: Your solution is definitely much better than mine. But I think it's better to attribute to the original solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137211

Comment: Thank you! but I still have one problem. I want to add more space between each value of the y-axis(the distance between each value of the axis is very small and makes it look messy) .So I want all the values of y to be shown in the plot. I want a neat plot so I want the value 0 to appear in the graph as a dividing line to make clear that the values ​​that are below are negative.

Comment: thanks @yarnabrina for finding the post with the interpolation code, I found it long time ago and did not remember it. Added to the answer.

Comment: @Jose Montoya I am not sure I understand your question. In your second image y-axis ticks are evenly distributed (the most usual). See camille comment in the original question

Comment: @Alfonso Hi, I have this problem https://ibb.co/3CWHCXP The plot is fine, but it's weird.

Comment: @Jose Montoya Hi, could you edit your question showing the code to generate the plot? otherwise is dificult to find the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Alfonso Hi, I've just edited my question. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: @Jose Montoya I edited my answer, hopefully this helps you to fix your problems. Keep us updated on your progress ;-) Best

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang

TB_ARG_since_1990 <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
                        1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
                        2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
), saldo = c(8275867, 3702514, -2636805, -3665755, -5751042, 
             841426, 48908, -4019329, -4943662, -2199522, 1060542, 6223146, 
             16661053, 16087980, 12130455, 11699873, 12392519, 11272844, 12556386, 
             16885829, 11381863, 9020415, 12008167, 1521176, 2668277.78157, 
             -3419083.03045001, 2057032, -8308931, -3881619)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
ggplot(TB_ARG_since_1990,
       aes(x = year,
           y = saldo)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid",
            size = 1) +
  geom_area(fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can make the graph nicer by modifying this code.